# How can I remove words in a string, which occur more than once?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
$text = 'IvanFedorGalinaRomaIvanGalina';
```

How can I remove all words in that string, which occur more than ocne, without a separator?

I tried:

```
$array = explode ("", $ text);
$result = array_unique ($array); 
$text = implode ("", $ result);
echo $text;
echo "<br>";
```

The result outputs:

```
Ivan
Fedor
Galina
Roma
Ivan
Galina
```

Comment: Go here: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Or write your question in English

Comment: Splitting by uppercases might be a start, assuming they are guaranteed  to be there.

Comment: @Flosculus: I don't know, that guarantee is not clear in the question. The original string has this feature, but you can't be certain every string will have this feature. Maybe user5419467 can tell us ? It's guaranteed that the words have an upcase char at the start ? if that's the case it's easy to create a explode function for that, otherwise you would have to look for strings of a certain size, beggining with a min size all the way to half of the original string size.

Comment: @user5419467: держать дубликаты, или только уникальным?

Comment: Please use only english in this site.Google translator service translated as "keep duplicates, or just unique?" is that what you meant ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira: Question needs clarification and OP doesn't speak english.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

Split your string on uppercase letters with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). So you end up with an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ivan
    [1] => Feduor
    [2] => Galina
    [3] => Roma
    [4] => Ivan
    [5] => Galina
)
```

After that use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count how many times each word exists in the array:

```
Array
(
    [Ivan] => 2
    [Feduor] => 1
    [Galina] => 2
    [Roma] => 1
)
```

Then you filter this array with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and you only keep the words which occur once.

At the end use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the words as values in your array, which you then can [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to a string.

Code:

```
<?php

    $text = 'IvanFeduorGalinaRomaIvanGalina';

    $arr = preg_split("/(?=[\p{Lu}])/u", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $unique = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($arr), function($v){
        return $v == 1;
    }));

    echo implode("", $unique);

?>
```

output:

```
FeduorRoma
```

Comment: only stroke letters, uppercase for example.

Comment: ?? didn't understand. What are "stroke letters" ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira (stroke letters/uppercase) It's a rather old term and used by signpainters (paint stroke) way back before any of us were probably born. http://letterheads40.com/content/block-letter-sign-painters-bread-butter

Comment: In your link there was only classe's summary. I tried to google it a bit but couldn't say I really undertood it. I'm not a native english speaker. AFAIU it's letters that are different from the rest of the message/word/phare in order to catch your attention or give greater importance to some word as uppercase normally do, but it can be done some other way as changing color or using bold. Is that it ?

Answer (score 1):

If upper case splits don't work for you, an alternative might be to simply recurse through regular expressions until you don't have repeats.  You'd need to specify a minimum number of characters of course.

```
<?php

$text = 'IvanFedorGalinaRomaIvanGalina';

$pattern = '/((.{4,}).*)\\2/';
$replacement = '\\1';

$text=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text, 1, $count);
while ($count > 0) {
  $text=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text, 1, $count);
}

print $text . "\n";
```

This continues to try replacements on 4+ character "words" until there are no more replacements to do.